# How to create 1000 objects (for example cube , sphere, cylinder) randomly in opengl?

Tags: opengl, random

I created a room. This is my code for the room's floor:

```
    void room(){
    glColor3f(1.0, 1.0 ,0.0);  
    glNormal3f(0,1,0);
    glVertex3f( 500 ,-3.0, 500); 
    glVertex3f(-500 ,-3.0, 500); 
    glVertex3f(-500 ,-3.0,-500); 
    glVertex3f( 500 ,-3.0,-500); 
}
```

Now I want to generate a lot of objects like cube , sphere , cylinder on the floor randomly. Can you help me How to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Quality question requires quality response*

```
for (int i = 0; i < 50000; i++) {
  glPushMatrix();
  glTranslatef(-500 + rand() % 1000, 7 + rand() % 100, -500 + rand() % 1000);
  glutSolidTeapot(10);
  glPopMatrix();
}
```

or might as well without glut

```
GLUquadric* q = gluNewQuadric();
for (int i = 0; i < 50000; i++) {
  glPushMatrix();
  glTranslatef(-500 + rand() % 1000, 7 + rand() % 100, -500 + rand() % 1000);
  gluSphere(q, 10, 10, 10);
  glPopMatrix();
}
gluDeleteQuadric(q);
```